# Jquery trigger <ul><li> in react js

Tags: reactjs

In react js ES6 I have `onclick` event for `ul` `li` `a`

```
<ul id="profiles">
<li><a href="" onclick="this.getValue('parameter')">Some Text</a></li>
<li><a href="" onclick="this.getValue('parameter')">Some Text</a></li>
<li><a href="" onclick="this.getValue('parameter')">Some Text</a></li>
<li><a href="" onclick="this.getValue('parameter')">Some Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

The above code is working fine on click. But on body load I want to trigger click event for one of the li link.

The code I'm using for trigger click event is :

`$("#profiles li:nth-child(2) a").click();`

But the above written jquery code event is not triggering, please do help me how to get click event on body load for one of `<li><a> </a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `paramter` to the getValue descriminates as to which `li's anchor` element was clicked you can call teh `getValue` function directly in `componentDidMount` function like

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getvalues('Second li');
}
```

Sinceyou are using ES6, you can call the react `onClick` function in ES6 style like

```
<ul id="profiles">
<li><a href="" onclick={this.getValue.bind(this,'parameter')}>Some Text</a></li>
<li><a href="" onclick={this.getValue.bind(this,'parameter')}">Some Text</a></li>
<li><a href="" onclick={this.getValue.bind(this,'parameter')}">Some Text</a></li>
<li><a href="" onclick={this.getValue.bind(this,'parameter')}">Some Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Still if you want to persist with Jquery you need to get the `DOMNode` like

```
$(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.myRefs[2])).click();
```

DOM

```
<ul id="profiles">
    <li><a href="" onclick={this.getValue.bind(this,'parameter')} ref={(inp) => this.myRefs[0] = inp}>Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="" onclick={this.getValue.bind(this,'parameter')} ref={(inp) => this.myRefs[1] = inp}>Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="" onclick={this.getValue.bind(this,'parameter')} ref={(inp) => this.myRefs[2] = inp}>Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="" onclick={this.getValue.bind(this,'parameter')} ref={(inp) => this.myRefs[3] = inp}>Some Text</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply shubham. When add ref={(inp)=>this.myRefs[i]=inp} I'm getting error as "TypeError: Cannot set property '4' of undefined at ref". Googled on that issue, but coudn't get solution..

Comment: @BhushanD you have to initialize or define this.myRefs